# convert struct pointer to interface{}

Tags: pointers, struct, interface, go

If I have:

```
   type foo struct{
   }

   func bar(baz interface{}) {
   }
```

The above are set in stone - I can't change foo or bar. Additionally, baz must converted back to a foo struct pointer inside bar. How do I cast &foo{} to interface{} so I can use it as a parameter when calling bar?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To turn `*foo` into an `interface{}` is trivial:

```
f := &foo{}
bar(f) // every type implements interface{}. Nothing special required
```

In order to get back to a `*foo`, you can either do a **[type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)**:

```
func bar(baz interface{}) {
    f, ok := baz.(*foo)
    if !ok {
        // baz was not of type *foo. The assertion failed
    }

    // f is of type *foo
}
```

Or a **[type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)** (similar, but useful if `baz` can be multiple types):

```
func bar(baz interface{}) {
    switch f := baz.(type) {
    case *foo: // f is of type *foo
    default: // f is some other type
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if you dont know the type of interface? `baz` in your example

Comment: @JuandeParras: If you don't know what kind of types `baz` might be, then you will have to work with reflection (`import "reflect"`). This is how packages like `encoding/json` can encode basically any type without knowing before hand.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with slices?

Comment: i dont get this. you are sending an object with address of struct foo but in the function it accepts an interface? when I try this and print the type using fmt.Printf it says the type is a struct pointer, not interface ....

Comment: @SaimMahmood `fmt.Printf` will always receive its arguments as interfaces. What it does is telling you the type _inside_ the interface. That means that `fmt.Printf("%T", f)` and `fmt.Printf("%T", interface{}(f))` is the same. The only difference is that in the latter, I did a redundant explicit conversion.

Answer (score 6):

use reflect

```
reflect.ValueOf(myStruct).Interface().(newType)
```

Comment: `reflect` can do this, but it's a heavy and dangerous way of conversion. There is a much easier way, described in accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a struct to interface can be achieved like this.
Where i is an assign data structure.

var j interface{} = &i

Comment: This is should be the right answer, so from the question it can be something like this:

var newFoo interface{} = &foo{}

bar(newFoo)

Answer (score 0):

Not fully-related, but I googled the question "convert interface struct to pointer" and get here.

So, just make a note: to convert an `interface of T` to `interface of *T`:

```
//
// Return a pointer to the supplied struct via interface{}
//
func to_struct_ptr(obj interface{}) interface{} {
    vp := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(obj))
    vp.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(obj))
    return vp.Interface()
}
```