# How do i recover the struct type after make it as Interface in Golang

Tags: go

I want to merge some similar func code to one func, but every old func is use different type of struct, so i intend to create the model by different string of type.
SO i do something like this:

```
type A struct {
   filed string
}
type B struct {
   filed string
}
and still C, D, E, F here...(every struct has its own method different with others)
```

and i want create those type in one place:

```
create(typeName string) interface {
   switch typeName {
   case A:
       return &A{}
   case B:
       return &B{}
   ....(more case than 10 times)
   }
}
```

Then i use the create() here:

```
model := create("A")
```

now, `model` is type of interface, and no A`s fileds, how would simply to recover the type of model to A

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast interface {} to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852393/how-to-cast-interface-to-struct)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how you can use [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to convert interfaces to underlying structs

Here `e` is of the struct type and hence you can access any of its fields or struct methods.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    AF int
}

type B struct {
    BF string
}

func main() {
    ds := []interface{}{
        A{1},
        B{"foo"},
    }

    for _, d := range ds {
        switch e := d.(type) {
        case A:
            fmt.Println(e.AF)
        case B:
            fmt.Println(e.BF)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. Would there is a way to avoid using `type assertion`, there are too much switch/case and broken the original logic. I hope i can use the `Model` just like original type

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way. You pay for abstraction as much as it really costs.